# nullable datetimes

Tags: c#

I have 1 datetime field that is not nullable and 1 that is nullable.  I can use the following code with the non nullable one :

```
 c.StartDate.Day.ToString() + "/" + 
 c.StartDate.Month.ToString() + "/" + 
 c.StartDate.Year.ToString()
```

But when I try to do this with the nullable one, I get the error :

> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'Day' and no extension method 'Day' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I get the Day, Month, Year of a nullable datetime?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You'll have to use the `.Value` property on your nullable:

```
c.StartDate.Value.Day.ToString()  //etc
```

After checking for `null`, you could:

```
 c.StartDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Comment: But check HasValue first if needed

Comment: I would also add a null check or use .GetValueOrDefault() to be safe.

Comment: Alternatively, you can assign a new variable cast to a non-nullable DateTime - `var startDate = (DateTime)c.StartDate;`, and then `startDate.Day` should work.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(c.StartDate.HasValue)
{
  DateTime sd = c.StartDate.Value;
  str = sd.Day.ToString() + "/" + sd.Month.ToString() + "/" + sd.Year.ToString()
}
else
  str = "some alternative for when there's no date";
```

Simpler still:

```
string str = c.StartDate.HasValue ? c.StartDate.value.ToString(@"d\/M\/yyyy") ? "some alternative for when there's no date";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(c.EndDate.HasValue)
{
    c.EndDate.Value.Day.ToString() + ...
}
```

You might also want to check the `ToString()` of the date and convert it to a string with just one formatting pattern and without concatination.

Answer (score 0):

What would you like the result to be? "//"

You could create extension methods which return "", but you still have the issue of what you want the final result to actually be.