# Some problems using ToShortDateString() method on a nullable DateTime object, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I have the following problem.

In a class I declare:

```
vulnerabilityDetailsTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currentVuln.Published.ToString(), _fontNormale)) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 30, PaddingTop = 10 });
```

and the interesting part is: **currentVuln.Published.ToString()**. This work fine.

**Published** is a **DateTime** property declared as **nullable**, in this way:

```
public System.DateTime? Published { get; set; }
```

The problem is that in the previous way the printed value of **currentVuln.Published.ToString()** is something like **18/07/2014 00:00:00** (also the time is included in the date).

I want show only the date and not show the time so I tryed to use something like it:

```
currentVuln.Published.ToShortDateString()
```

But it don't work and I obtain the following error message in Visual Studio:

> Error 4   'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a
>   definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method
>   'ToShortDateString' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\PdfVulnerability.cs   93  101 PdfReport

It seems that this happen because my DateTime field is nullable.

What am i missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: create your own method with a nullable date parameter and return whatever you like. eg. if myDate == null return "" else... ;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125163/nullable-datetimes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're right, it's because your `DateTime` field is nullable.

The extension methods for a `DateTime` are unavailable for `DateTime?`, but to understand why, you have to realize that there actually is no `DateTime?` class.

Most commonly, we write nullable types using the `?` syntax, like `DateTime?`, `int?`, etc as you did above. But that's just [syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109872/301857) for `Nullable<DateTime>`, `Nullable<int>`, etc.

```
public Nullable<DateTime> Published { get; set; }
```

And all those apparently separate `Nullable` types come from a single [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) [`Nullable<T>` struct](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e) that wraps your type and provides two helpful properties:

- `HasValue` (for testing whether the underlying wrapped type has a value), and
- `Value` (for accessing that underlying value, assuming there is one)

Check to make sure there's a value first, then use the `Value` property to access the underlying type (in this case, a `DateTime`), along with any methods that are normally available for that type.

```
if (currentVuln.Published.HasValue)
{
    // not sure what you're doing with it, so I'll just assign it...

    var shortDate = currentVuln.Published.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

For C# 6.0 and higher you can use [null conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072/what-does-question-mark-and-dot-operator-mean-in-c-sharp-6-0) instead of `.Value`:

```
    var shortDate = currentVuln.Published?.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: @AndreaNobili The reason this happens is the nullable DateTime hides/encapsulates the actual value inside of it, so it has no `ToShortDateString()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone else comes across this thread. You can use .value.ToShortDateString(). This will solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The value type `Nullable<>` encapsulates a value of another value type together with a boolean `hasValue`.

This type `Nullable<>` inherits the method `string ToString()` from its ultimate base class, `System.Object`. It also overrides this method with a new implementation. The new implementation returns `""` if `hasValue` is `false`, and returns the string it gets from `.ToString()` on the encapsulated value (which also inherits `System.Object`) if `hasValue` is `true`.

That is why your existing code is legal.

The type `Nullable<>` does not have any method `ToShortDateString`, though. You would have to go to the encapsulated value, through the `Value` property. Therefore, instead of the illegal:

```
currentVuln.Published.ToShortDateString()    /* error */
```

you will need

```
currentVuln.Published.HasValue ? currentVuln.Published.Value.ToShortDateString() : ""
```

or, equivalently

```
currentVuln.Published != null ? currentVuln.Published.Value.ToShortDateString() : ""
```

(both do the same at runtime). You could change the string `""` to something else, like `"never"` or `"not published"` if you wanted.

If it could be a problem that the `Published` property (its `get` accessor) is called twice, you would need to take out a temporary variable somewhere, `var published = currentVuln.Published;`, and use that: `published.HasValue ? published.Value.ToShortDateString() : ""`